# Binary search on custom list - android

Tags: java, android, collections

In my `adapter` of `recyclerView` I am compare two list like bellow :

```
for (int i = 0; i < existImages.size(); i++) {
  if (jsonInstagramList.get(position).getId().equalsIgnoreCase(existImages.get(i).getImageID())) {
    holder.insertedProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    break;
  } else {
    holder.insertedProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

`existImages` is `private List<ExistImage> existImages;` and `jsonInstagramList` is `private List<Node> jsonInstagramList;` .

How can I use from `binary search` for speed up in this search or other ways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your context, this could be pretty simple.

There is already a binary search implemented within the Collections class (link to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T))). So you simply call that method.

Of course, keep in mind:

> Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm. The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements...

This means that your list should already be sorted. So, the real answer is to first look at your current loop:

```
jsonInstagramList.get(position).getId().equalsIgnoreCase(existImages.get(i).getImageID()
```

to find that you simply can't turn this into a binary search.

In other words: if this code to *find* elements is called so often that it using binary search is required - then you have to **prepare** your data upfront.

Meaning: binary search finds a *key* within a sorted list of elements of the same type. So you first have to **create** a list that contains those things you want to search for!

Comment: How can I use from binarySearch on two list ?

Comment: You got an update. And the real answer here: you should probably step back and read how/what binary search. Your comment implies that you assume this is some magic thing that can be applied to anything. And that is not the case.